# Laravel 5.1 AJAX Response always causes a connection reset

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, ember.js

I have a problem with a Laravel AJAX response. 
The request is GET not POST
This is the API URL: 
http://example.com/app/public/index.php/api/userdata 
and I never receive an AJAX response. 
In my Chrome browser I get the following error `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`,
but when I go to the API URL directly from Chrome
I get the JSON response and it's correct. 
This only happens for AJAX requests
and I also have "Provisional headers are shown" in my AJAX request.
I'm using Ember for AJAX requests, but I also tried using jQuery `$.getJSON` 
and I got the same result.

I read some discussion about "Laravel Connection Reset" and I tried to disable opcache but this is still happening.
This is my enviroment

- PHP Version 7.0
- Laravel 5.1.39(LTS)
- Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
- jQuery 1.11.3
- Ember 2.0.2

This is my controller code :

```
 public function index()
  {
      $inputs = Input::all();
      $userData = UserData::inMyCompany();
      if(isset($inputs['filters']))
      {
          foreach($inputs['filters'] as $field => $value)
          {
              $userData->where($field, '=', $value);
          }
      }
      $userData->with([
         'userDataRelation1',
         'userDataRelation2',
      ]);
      $userData = $userData->get();
      return Response::json($userData);
  }
```

This is my JavaScript code :

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
     <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         var url = 'http://example.com/app/public/index.php/api/userdata?filters[id]=633';
         $.getJSON(url, function(response){
             console.log(response);
         });
     });
     </script>
```

Why does the AJAX request always return a "Connection Reset" ? 
What is the possible cause for this ? 
How to fix the problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show us the controller code and the js code (that does the ajax request

Comment: Hi Achraf i just updated my question with controller and js code. 
thanks

Comment: try to comment all that and just keep this       `return Response::json(['test' => 'success' );`

Comment: other actions work fine or not?

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja
return Response::json(['test' => 'success' );

if only this code. yes it works.

Comment: @weigreen for other ajax Request to another api url. 
there are several that's work. but for this api url api/userData it's always get connection reset

Comment: I have a similar connection reset problem in laravel 5.5. Please see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54130437/laravel-5-5-why-is-exception-not-thrown-by-foreign-key-violation-from-delete-met